# Visited links within spoilers are not hidden anymore

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, hyperlinks, spoilers

This [answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/14902/4450) contains spoilers. Once you've clicked any of the links, your browser remembers you've visited them and the stylesheet applies new styles to them, which prevent them from being hidden normally by the spoiler:

[image]

It's a similar situation for this [answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/14905/4450):

[image]

Comment: They are all hidden for me. I'm using Firefox 38 on a Mac. Does this still occur in safe mode for you? Have you tried with a new profile?

Comment: Yes, it still occurs in safe mode.

Comment: I can reproduce this in Chrome. The links get a different style applied to them once they've been visited, which doesn't allow them to be hidden by the spoiler anymore. The reason you can't reproduce it in Chrome or on a new profile is because the links aren't remembered as visited in those places.

Comment: Repro-ed in IE11/Win7 as well.

Comment: repro-ed in Chrome / Ubuntu 14

Comment: Good catch @animuson

Comment: Related, from the Meta of the site those posts are on: [Should we consider adding links in spoiler tags?](http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/2948)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spoiler CSS rules didn't consider visited links, so those got rendered fully.

This has been fixed and will be with you in the next build.

Comment: Please, see http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/26025/links-in-spoilers-arent-hidden I did not visit the link in the spoiler.

Comment: Looks like the CSS rules on maths are still wrong. Fixing.