# Links to related posts in spoiler block should not be shown

Tags: feature-request, hyperlinks, linked-questions, spoilers

A bit of a small issue I have:

When I put a link to a related post within a spoiler block, it becomes a bit of a spoiler that the linked question becomes visible on the side-bar.

For example:

In [my answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/118180/21267) to the question [Has anyone known married for love in Westeros?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/118125/had-anyone-known-married-for-love), I have a spoiler block. Within that block I link to a post (which also happens to be a somewhat spoiler-ish post). Now anyone reading the question will see that one of the linked posts is spoilerish. See this image for example (complete with free hand circle):

[image: Screen capture of issue in question: Part 1]

[image: Screen capture of issue in question: Part 1]

**Can we assume that a link to an internal post within a spoiler block is inherently a spoiler and not include it in the "linked questions" sidebar?**

Like I said, [small problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_World_problem)...

**ETA:**
I should point out that the issue I'm bringing up is not [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/256941/252593); my concern is the link in the **sidebar**. Thanks **@Catija** for bringing that post to my attention.

Comment: As an aside, the reason this is a bit of an issue for me is that I'm reluctant to link to existing posts if I think that someone might be spoiled by the very fact that they see a spoiler in the sidebar...