# Links within spoilers are not hidden on the Revisions page

Tags: bug, design, hyperlinks, revisions-list, spoilers

Similar to [Visited links within spoilers are not hidden anymore](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/256941/295232), links in spoilers aren't properly hidden on Revisions pages like [this one](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/posts/62085/revisions).

[image]

Tested on the latest versions of Safari, Firefox and Chrome on macOS 10.13.3.