# Visible links inside spoilers in revision history

Tags: bug, revisions-list, spoilers

The spoiler markdown usually does a good job of hiding the content inside them. E.g., consider this year's [❄️ Winter Bash 2019 Hat list ❄️](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/339891/%ef%b8%8f-winter-bash-2019-hat-list-%ef%b8%8f/339894#339894):

[image]

However, oddly enough, if you take a look at the post's [revision history](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/339894/revisions), the links are clearly visible "through" the spoiler styling:

[image]

System details:

- OS: Windows 10 Enterprise, 1803
- Browser: Google Chrome Version 78.0.3904.108 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: @rene I was just browsing through my own questions and it turns out there's even an older dupe: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/308093/295232